# Extracting numerical values from sublist items

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list with sublists, such as:

```
a = [['CW50', 'GKB15', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5'], ['CW50', 'GKB12.5', 'GKBi12.5'], ['CW50', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5'], ['CW50', 'GKF12.5', 'GKBi15', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5']]
```

and I want to extract only the numerical values out of it, but maintaining the form of the sublists.
Like this:

```
b = [[50, 15, 12.5, 12.5], [50, 12.5, 12.5], [50, 12.5, 12.5], [50, 12.5, 15, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5]]
```

I found a solution using re.findall but I cant get to keep the sublist structure.

My code:

```
b = []

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        b.append(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", j))

OUTPUT:
b =  [50, 15, 12.5, 12.5, 50, 12.5, 12.5, 50, 12.5, 12.5, 50, 12.5, 15, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sublists within `b`:

```
b = []

for i in a:
    b.append([])
    for j in i:
        b[-1].append(float(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", j)[0]))
```

Or, for a for comprehension:

```
b = [[float(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", j)[0]) for j in i] for i in a]
```

Both give:

```
[[50.0, 15.0, 12.5, 12.5], [50.0, 12.5, 12.5], [50.0, 12.5, 12.5], [50.0, 12.5, 15.0, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, simply add another inner list that you extend to:

```
import re

a = [['CW50', 'GKB15', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5'], ['CW50', 'GKB12.5', 'GKBi12.5'],
     ['CW50', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5'], 
     ['CW50', 'GKF12.5', 'GKBi15', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5', 'GKB12.5']]

b = []

for i in a:
    c = []       # add inner list here
    for j in i:
        c.extend(re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", j))

    # convert all to float
    c = list(map(float,c))

    b.append(c)


print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[50.0, 15.0, 12.5, 12.5], [50.0, 12.5, 12.5], [50.0, 12.5, 12.5], 
 [50.0, 12.5, 15.0, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5]]
```